# How is this object in 4D, and why is the convex hull the complete graph?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I just want an idea, not a full analysis. Here is the object I'm talking about:

[image]

This object was given in my computational geometry class. If you don't understand the picture, this is how I would explain it:

- Take a bicycle's wheel, and lay it down flat on a table
- Take another wheel, and stand it up on the table, then lift the wheel a little bit (so there's a gap between the table and the wheel)
- But actually the 'standing' wheel is **above** the wheel lying flat on the table

Then, consider points on the perimeter of the wheel (but not the points in the center of the circle, I don't know why I drew them). We take $\frac{n}{2}$ points from both wheels.

**Question:** My professor said this object in 4d will have the 'complete graph' as the convex hull. I have no clue how to interpret this.

I know what convex hulls are. But suppose a set of points lies on a 2d plane. I don't see why the 2d convex hull is not a 3d convex hull as well. What I'm saying is that this object exists in 3d, so why can't it's 3d convex hull be the 4d convex hull as well?

I would also like to add, this was given as a quick example, and not really discussed in detail, so I might have mis-understood something (I have a suspicion that the 4d part is a mistake by me, and it's actually an example of a set of points in 3d whose convex hull is the complete graph). If I am mistaken, then the question is why is the convex hull the complete graph (as in all possible edges are in the convex hull)?

I don't even know the name of this object, so I can't google it.

Comment: If the hexagonal hull was taken in 3d, we would get what is called an antiprism with an example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecagonal_antiprism)

Comment: Even in 3Dthe above two projections are not defining the object - the third projection could be a circle (3D sphere) or a square, or many other types of objects. In 4D there are even more variants.